# Send back press event to underlying activity

Tags: android, view, event-handling, accessibilityservice

Actually my hardware back button is not working. So what I am trying to build is a floating view on whose click I can send the back press to current activity (since my floating view is not on focus, hence the activity under the overlay is in focus).

So I was able to build an overlay view using the following code

```
private void initialiseChatHead()
{
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_back);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());
    setOnTouchListener(params);
}
```

and I thought since its not in focus dispatching the back key will go to the underlying activity but this did not work.

```
@Override 
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        v.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
        return false;
    } 
}
```

While searching about how to do this, I came across this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.app58us.backkey), which is doing the exact same thing. I think it uses AccessibilityService for this but I don't know how. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this (sending back press to the underlying activity). Thanks!

Comment: it's been a while, but I'm trying to do the exact same thing and was wondering if you have any feedback in this matter?